# At which age child hops on one leg?

Tags: pre-schooler, development

My four years ten months old son is able to hop with right leg.Balance in one leg for 20 seconds.He is not able to hop with left leg.How to teach him to hop with left leg?He have less strength in left leg than right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [an article in Science Daily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/02/130221084602.htm), the ability to hop on one leg develops between 3 to 5 years of age, so your son should be close to the point where he can hop on both legs.  There is still some time to develop this skill, and practice might help him get the hang of it, but since you mention that his left leg seems to lack strength compared to the right, this is something you should bring up with your son's doctor.  While it may be nothing at all, and he just needs a little more time and hopping practice, one-sided weakness can be marker for health or developmental problems, so it's best to get that checked out.